# Android Sqlite Update increase value issue

Tags: android, sqlite

The problem is that the following code works just fine for the first time I update a column value, but it refuses to increase it the next times.

```
public void incrementValue(Context context, String number) {

     SwipeDatabaseHelper mOpenHelper = new SwipeDatabaseHelper(
          context.getApplicationContext());

     String sql = "UPDATE " + DatabaseContract.PATH_CONTACTS + " SET "
          + DatabaseContract.DatabaseEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_UNREAD + " = " +
          DatabaseContract.DatabaseEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_UNREAD + " + 1 WHERE "
          + DatabaseContract.DatabaseEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_NUM + " = ?";

     mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase().execSQL(sql, new String[]{number});
}
```

It is very interesting that when I update it with a hard coded value (for example 0) it goes perfectly. And when I call the function again it only increments it by one and the value never goes above 1 even if you call it a thousand times

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
  private final static String DATABASE_NAME = "persistent.db";
  private final static int CUR_DATABASE_VERSION = 4;

  public SwipeDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
      super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, CUR_DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    final String CONTACTS = "CREATE TABLE USER (" +
        DatabaseEntry._ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        DatabaseEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_NUM + " TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT ''," +
        DatabaseEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT ''," +
        DatabaseEntry.COULUMN_CONTACT_SURNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT ''," +
        DatabaseEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_USERNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT ''," +
        DatabaseEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_UNREAD + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0," +
        DatabaseEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_URL + " TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT ''," +
        "UNIQUE(" + DatabaseEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_NUM + ") ON CONFLICT REPLACE);";

    final String GROUPS = "CREATE TABLE GROUPS (" +
        DatabaseEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        DatabaseEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_NUM + " TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT ''," +
        DatabaseEntry.COLUMN_GROUP_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT ''," +
        DatabaseEntry.COLUMN_GROUP_IMAGE + " TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT ''," +
        DatabaseEntry.COLUMN_GROUP_OWNER + " TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT ''," +
        DatabaseEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_UNREAD + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0," +
        "UNIQUE(" + DatabaseEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_NUM + ") ON CONFLICT REPLACE);";

    db.execSQL(CONTACTS);
    db.execSQL(GROUPS);

  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS USER");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS GROUPS");
    onCreate(db);
  }
}
```

So the same call works for User table, but behaves strangely for Groups table.

Comment: COLUMN_CONTACT_NUM have INTEGER type, no?

Comment: Just to avoid any problem try instead of new String[]{number} use new Integer[]{Integer.valueOf( number)}

Comment: by the way, please post a Log.d to see the value of sql variable

Comment: COLUMN_CONTACT_NUM has strangely TEXT  type) Anyway, I have another similar table and the same execution works good, but this very update is getting me annoyed

Comment: please post the entire class i want to recreate the enviroment here just for fun ;)